# To implement Donation functionality using paypal

Tags: android, paypal

I want to implement the Donation functionality using Paypal for a android application which is generating donation for a cause. There are three options to implement
1) Using Native SDK 
2) Using webview
3) Redirect to webpage on browser

If i go with the first option, then it is possible to replace the button (**Buy a Thing**) with label '**Donate**' shown in sample application of Paypal [Paypal sample app for integrating SDK in native app](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp)

[image: Sample app home screen]

As i am using the donation option in native app instead of In App Purchase. In this case,
Will Google suspend my application from Google play store?.

If above case is true, In that case, do i have to go with the second option (WebView) OR this webview option is also not possible as it is also the part of native application.

And Hence i have to redirect a user to the browser for a donation if above options are not true.

Please let me know the correct option.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you find a solution for this? I also want to implement Donate feature in my application. What I want is just to include a button "Donate" (Android native button). When user clicks on this button, I want him to redirect on PayPal website with necessary information. So that he can complete donation on that webview/webpage. And after successful donation, it comes back to my app.